# Handling image masks and borders when exporting Sketch to Adobe XD

Tags: svg, sketch-app, adobe-xd

I am trying to export some of my current designs, made in Sketch App, to Adobe XD so I can make small prototypes out of them.

I don't want to be remaking these in XD, so I export them instead. However, the file has a number of image masks that don't export well in the recommended SVG.

Is there a way around this?
When converting these masks to bitmap it includes any layer styles such as borders as well and I need to be able to influence these things for ie hover styles. The borders seem to render weird in XD anyway, see screenshot:

[image: masks break]
[image: masks complete]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you work with artboards in Sketch. Let's say you have 5 artboards. Select all your elements from your first artboard and put them outside of your artboard.

Now all your elements are outside. Press escape or click somewhere so you can deselect your elements. Then, select all your elements again(but now you've selected only your elements and not your artboard). Copy your selected elements (press Cmd+C), go to Adobe XD, select an artboard and with the artboard selected paste your selected elements (press Cmd+V).

Adobe XD for some great reason understands Sketch elements(rectangles,text,masks) reasonably well. Do the same process for your other artboards. The trick is to select you elements without selecting the artboard on Sketch. If you select elements inside a Sketch artboard and paste them in Adobe XD it won't work.

Now all your elements are editable in some way and your can easily select any element so you can make your prototype.